# Android app the send video over wifi to another phone

Tags: android, video, monitoring, mobile, display

I am looking for an android app where two phones work in conjunction to send video.

One of them is taking video, and sending it over wifi to the other android device that is displaying it.

The use case would be getting visuals of hard to reach places.

Comment: I haven't tried one of them, but take a look at my list of [Streaming apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_video_streaming). One of the "Baby monitors" might be a good fit.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [IP WebCam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&hl=en)

1. Create a hotspot from the "camera" phone.
2. Join the hotspot on the "viewer" phone.
3. Open the app on IPWebcam on the camera phone.
4. Open a browser and connect to the address indicated on the IP webcam
   app.
5. And now you can view the video link.

You also can try Airdroid.
Works in a similar way, but Airdroid is less cut out for this kinda work.

Another Guide that can help you out.

PS. You dont have to hotspot, as long as there is a form of wifi connection it should work